# Shopify Supply Theme - How do I vertically centre the items on the nav bar?

Tags: html, css, shopify

So I've already changed this from the initial layout, but this is how my nav bar currently looks:

[Nav Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvmBc.png)

And this is the code that I've botched:

```
<nav class="nav-bar" role="navigation">
<div class="wrapper">      
  <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-item large--one-half">
        {% include 'site-nav' %}
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item large--one-half text-right">
        <a href="/cart" class="header-cart-btn cart-toggle">
        <span class="icon icon-cart"></span>
        {{ 'layout.cart.cart' | t }} <span class="cart-count cart-badge--desktop {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}hidden-count{% endif %}">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
        </a> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

So my question is: is there another botch that I can write in to make the navigation buttons and the cart button level with each other? I've had a play around for a couple of hours and haven't got anywhere :(

Thanks in advance

Laura :)

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you gave your css. :D ... Alternatively, the providing of a JSFiddle example would be nice.

Comment: @JefréN. How do I do that? Sorry I'm really bad at this!!

Comment: Do what part? Adding the css for the navbar is done the same way you added the html. JSFiddle is used to fiddle around with the css, html and javascript for a particular project or idea. Here's an [example.](https://jsfiddle.net/welcome_me/z4tfyhdw/) JSFiddle examples are useful when someone is trying to figure out what your problem is. At this point, however, the `css` would probably be the most useful.

Answer (score 0):

your "grid-item large--one-half" classes are causing the grid items to be separated into 2 halves. If you were to add "text-align: center" to it for example, your menu would center to the limits of the parent div. You will have to make the menu div 100% of the width of the page, and then place the cart link absolute like so.

```
.cart {
position: absolute;
top: 7px;
right: 3%;
line-height: 50px;}
```

In terms of making the links the same height, you can add a line-height to everything so that the text will center in that defined height.

I created a quick fiddle to help answer some of this for you as a reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/zsrjmLrd/